# Simple Iterative Least Square Algorithms with two unknown variables in the same equation

Tags: r

Simple Iterative Least Square Algorithms with two unknown variables in the same equation

Given Equation (1) and data with variables y, d and m, I want to estimate α(αis between 0 and 1) through iterative square approach because β  in Equation (2) also contains the unknown estimate α
            log(y)=c-βlog⁡(d+2αm/(1-α))
Where
            2)        β=2/(1-α)

Steps for solving Iterative Square approach algorithms are,
    Starts with an initial guess of  α,e.g.,(α_0).
    Regress (1) with initial(α_0)  in place to get the parameter estimate β that is used to calculate a new (α_1).
    Use estimate βon (2) to calculate a new (α_1)
    Use α_1as the “new guess” and repeat steps 2 and 3 until the initial and new αconverge.

I develop the following R-code that follows the 4 steps. However, I would like to loop in steps 2 and 3 and stop the process after convergence (or near convergence-a little tolerance lance levels)

Data link.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/luhfcwyfuqousfb/AACOtOEddEDDnzBYsguQhkMGa?dl=0

```
#Clear working directory
# rm(list=ls()) 
# Set/Load  working directory
#setwd("C:\\Users\\Philipmunyua\\Google Drive\\nanoHUB research\\02 analysis\\04 develop level _test spatial\\02 input data")
# Generating alpha and model distribution
dat<-read.csv("t06_deg_freq.csv")
dat$X<-NULL
dat$ln_deg<-log(dat$degree)
dat$ln_freq<-log(dat$Freq)
summary(dat)
a<-0.98
a1<-range(0.000,1.000)
m<-(weighted.mean(dat$degree, dat$Freq)*0.5)
d<-as.matrix(dat$degree)
fd<-as.matrix(dat$Freq)
xd<-as.matrix(dat$degree+((2*m*a)/(1-a)))
y<-log(fd)
x<-log(xd)
fit <- lm(y ~ x, data=dat)
#summary(fit) # show results
b.fit<-coef(fit)
b<-b.fit[2]
t<-((b-2)/b)
a1<-ifelse(t>max(a1),max(a1),t)
```

Comment: since we don't have your files, this isn't a working example

Comment: Wouldn't this just involved setting up the problem with `nls`?

Comment: Added data url. I am not sure what nls means.